# Web Control included another Web Control?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to customize a webcontrol that can be used like this:

```
<cc1:TitleEx runat="server" Theme="Sky" DemoUrl="what.swf" Left="150" Width="250">
       <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</cc1:TitleEx>
```

The base class is:

```
[Bindable(true)]
[Category("Appearance")]
[DefaultValue("")]
[Localizable(true)]
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerDefaultProperty)]
public string Text
{
   get
   {
    String s = (String)ViewState["Text"];
    return ((s == null) ? String.Empty : s);
   }
   set
   {
    if (this.HasControls())
     {
        this.Controls.Clear();
     }
    ViewState["Text"] = value;
   }
  }

/// <summary>
/// child control's content
/// </summary>
protected StringBuilder HtmlContent = new StringBuilder();

protected override void AddParsedSubObject(object obj)
{
  if (obj is LiteralControl)
  {
    HtmlContent.Append(((LiteralControl)obj).Text);
    this.Text = HtmlContent.ToString();
  }
  else
  {
   if (obj != null)
   {
     HtmlContent.Append(GetControlHtml(obj as Control));
     this.Text = HtmlContent.ToString();
   }
  }
}

/// <summary>
/// get the child controls' html
/// </summary>
protected string GetControlHtml(Control ctl)
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   StringWriter tw = new StringWriter();
   HtmlTextWriter writer = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
   ctl.RenderControl(writer);
   sb.Append(writer.InnerWriter.ToString());
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

My problems are when I set a string to this literal control in `Page_Load()`, but the string cannot display. I also try to set the value in `OnPreInit()`, `OnPreLoad()` but still have no any luck.

Is there anybody has met this issue before?

How do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found out the answer by reflect the panel.
here is my solution.http://www.cnblogs.com/coolkiss/archive/2010/12/30/1921494.html